# forwarding of small and large packets: any difference?

Tags: ip, router, forwarding, packet

When it comes to simple **forwarding** of **packets** (no errors being generated), are packets processed faster by routers when they are **small** as opposed to when they contain a **large** payload?

Or do routers work exclusively on a **per-packet basis**, so regardless of the size of a packet, inside a queue every packet is treated equally?

Do you guys know any references I could read?

Answer (score 1):

Processed, as in routed? A small packet is routed as quickly as a large packet, though transmission time does vary depending upon the amount of data.

For example, a jumbo ethernet frame is routed at the same speed as a 100 byte frame, but the actual transmission time between the two will vary. And, of course, if the jumbo frame has to be fragmented due to a smaller MTU size on the transmitting interface, the packet will take longer to forward.

Also, after a packet is routed, it is delivered into a buffer for transmission, and if FIFO is being used, the packets are transmitted in the order they are received. QoS is a means of changing the order in which packets are queued to prioritize some packets over others.

I would recommend reading up on QoS, and cef (cisco express forwarding) for details.